# Haskell Matrix Addition/Subtraction

Tags: haskell, dictionary

this is what I have for matrix addition in Haskell

```
    > add :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
    > add [] [] = [] 
    > add (x:xs) (y:ys) = zipWith (+) x y : add xs ys
```

add [[1,2], [3,4]] [[5,6], [7,8]] gives me [[6,8],[10,12]]

However, I am trying do with one line instead

```
    > add :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
    > add = map ((zipWith (+))
```

How come the map function doesn't work?

Comment: Notice that you also have unbalanced parentheses...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `map` function doesn't work here because you're iterating over *two* lists instead of one.  To iterate over two lists in parallel, you use `zipWith`, just like you are already doing for the inner loop.

```
Prelude> let add = zipWith (zipWith (+))
Prelude> add [[1, 2], [3, 4]] [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
[[6,8],[10,12]]
```

Comment: Indeed, this generalizes to all n-dimensional lists.  To add two 4-dimensional tensors, you can say `(zipWith.zipWith.zipWith.zipWith) (+)`.

Answer (score 8):

`map` takes in a single list: you're trying to give it **two**.

Try something like:

```
add = zipWith (zipWith (+))
```